# YouTube Embed video Player with Web XR

Tags: youtube, video-player, webxr

I am using https://github.com/tylergregg/unity-webgl-youtube this GitHub page for YouTube Player in Unity Web GL and Web XR. Everything is working fine but when I enter in VR mode video is not rendering, but I am able to hear the sound of that video. I can't find what is the actual problem. Why its happening?

I have tried the above GitHub page for rendering embed YouTube videos and WebXR Export for VR rendering in Unity.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions, as in, when you have problems with the code you are writing. It is not a support site for any random code you find on the web. Please check the [tour] and [ask].